# How to get rid of the extra spacing?

Tags: html, css

You can find the staging environment over here:
http://axces-staging.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/

I have a lot of unnecessary spacing above the title "Onze aanpak".
I only have this issue on Firefox. It looks fine on chrome and safari.

[image]

Cannot find what causes this. Does someone have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to two values in the elements above that space:

1.) The `top: -30rem` in `homepage-middle__wrapper`

2.) The `margin-top: 30rem` in `section--products homepage-middle background--primary`

Erase both to eliminate that space.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove the negative value for top here:

```
.homepage-middle__wrapper {
    margin-bottom: -27rem;
    padding-top: 2.5rem;
    position: relative;
    top: -30rem;
}
```

Remove the margin-top here:

```
.homepage-middle {
    margin-top: 30rem;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

At a padding top to the container or wrapper to achieve the same effect as before.